# How to use border radios in a convex/ exterior way?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How I can make a border radios like in this picture?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvtKq.png)

This is what I did until now

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5dVm.png)

Until now I have this code:

```js
.sidebar__pages {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 20%;
}
.sidebar__page {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}


.sidebar__page-button {
  background-color: black;
  border-top-left-radius: 38px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 38px;
  //Here is the question ... how
}
```

```html
<ul className="sidebar__pages">
        <li className="sidebar__page">
          <NavLink to="/" className="sidebar__page-button" activeClassName="">
            Administrare
          </NavLink>
        </li>
```

Does anyone know please to help me find out how I can make this kind of border-radios?
Thank you in advance ! :D

Comment: Your image description is not matched with the snippet, try to provide the code till you have achieved that

Answer (score 0):

This might be a starting point for you:

```css
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999
}

ul {
  width: 100px;
  list-style: none;
}

li{
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

li.active{
  border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
   
  border-right: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

li.active::before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -21px;
  right: -20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  border-right: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

li.active::after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -21px;
  right: -20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  border-right: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks :) I will try  to work with it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample using two additional spans for the two corners. However there will be a problem with the menu shadow.

```css
.container {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 0;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 200px;
}

li {
    border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    
    
}
li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: grey;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left:20px   
}


li.active {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;  
    border-radius: 30px 0 0 30px;
    
}

li.active span.top {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    right: 0;
    
}

li.active span.top:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 0 0 #e2e2e2;
    
}

li.active span.bottom {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 0;
    
}

li.active span.bottom:before {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: 15px -15px 0 0 #e2e2e2;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="">Link 2</a><span class="top"></span><span class="bottom"></span></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I must say it's a very stupid design, easy to make with Photoshop but hard to code and is really useless.